# How to integrate Windows Store app with WinJS?

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, winjs

I have a Windows Store App developed under C#/XAML. How can i integrate this app with Windows JavaScript?

I need to view my app inside the WinJS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write apps in C#/XAML or Javascript where WinJS is a central part. Please explain more deeply what you want to achieve and what you have tried

Comment: I have a Windows Store application developed for Win8.1 and Win10(UWP). I need to integrate i mean need to use that application or embed that application in WinJS application. I need to use that Windows store application in WinJS without developing the same in WinJS.

Comment: Think about using contracts ( share, etc ) to interact. Besides that you can not display XAML controls in a WinJS app and because of sandboxing it probably is not possible to inline an app in a frame or something like this

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a C#/XAML application UI cannot be shown within a WinJS based application. There is no mechanism for hosting the UI. In fact, today, there's no way to host/use all or some of another application's UI within an application (even XAML with XAML). The best you can do today is launch another app.

You could host a WinJS application inside a `WebView` in a C#/XAML app. But, that's not what you're trying to do.